Second Order Derivative
This is the question
This is the answer
I understand the first derivative which is $$ \frac{\partial{E_n}}{\partial{w}} = \frac{\partial{E_n}}{\partial{y_n}} \frac{\partial{y_n}}{\partial{w}} $$
But, I do not understand how they are deriving $$ \frac{\partial^2{E_n}}{\partial{w^2}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{y_n}}\frac{\partial{E_n}}{\partial{w}} \frac{\partial{y_n}}{\partial{w}} $$
Shouldn't it be
$$ \frac{\partial^2{E_n}}{\partial{w^2}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{w}}(\frac{\partial{E_n}}{\partial{y_n}} \frac{\partial{y_n}}{\partial{w}}) $$
I must admit that I am a bit rusty on my calculus, so I am probably making some trivial error.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Please write the question in the body without passing to a link.

$$ \frac{\partial^2{E_n}}{\partial{w^2}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{w}}(\frac{\partial{E_n}}{\partial{y_n}} \frac{\partial{y_n}}{\partial{w}}) $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2{E_n}}{\partial{w^2}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{w}}\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{y_n}}\frac{\partial{E_n}}{\partial{w}} \frac{\partial{y_n}}{\partial{w}} $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2{E_n}}{\partial{w^2}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{y_n}}\frac{\partial{E_n}}{\partial{w}} \frac{\partial{y_n}}{\partial{w}} $$

Why the downvote? It seems like a proper answer to me. I wish I could upvote you but I do not have enough reputation.

Thank you @Abhishek
